# How can I translate/describe a "rough idle" to the mechanic?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

I need to take my vehicle to a mechanic to diagnose a problem with a rough idle.  How do I translate this term, "rough idle" to Spanish?

> Explanation of "Rough idle"
>
> Have you ever been told your car’s engine **idles rough**? Not exactly sure what that means? It’s likely you’ve experienced a **rough idling** vehicle – which just means *the car feels rough and bouncy when the engine is running*
>
> Source: [COMMON CAUSES OF A ROUGH IDLING ENGINE](https://takeit2thehouse.com/common-causes-of-a-rough-idling-engine/)

Comment: If the mechanic were Argentinean, you should tell him: "Hace ruido al regular."

Answer (score 9):

In Spain, "idle" is often translated as [*ralentí*](http://dle.rae.es/ralent%C3%AD). Your car's condition could be translated as:

- My car has a rough idle. -> *Mi coche tiene un ralentí ruidoso.* / *Mi coche vibra cuando está al ralentí.*

Comment: nunca había escuchado esta palabra... definitivamente no se usa en todas partes.

Comment: No es palabra usual en Argentina.

Comment: In regions where *'marchar en ralentí'* isn't used, the phras *['marchar en vacío'](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=jkNO5ULorDXX2INc2Abn)* may be an alternative.

Comment: @leonbloy En Argentina se usa "regular" como opuesto a "acelerar". En los dos casos el motor está en marcha (no parado). El ruido o la vibración puede observarse cuando se regula o cuando se acelera.

Answer (score 5):

Unas búsquedas en Google revelan que una expresión común es también «[ralentí inestable](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ralent%C3%AD%20inestable%22)».

- Ralentí inestable: 30.300 resultados.
- Ralentí irregular: 5.100 resultados.
- Ralentí ruidoso: 72 resultados.

Las búsquedas sobre «vibración» y «ralentí» también tienen muchos resultados, pero gran parte de ellos se refieren a vibraciones molestas de alta frecuencia del motor, las ventanas, la carrocería, etc. Me parece que Flimzy se refiere a que el contador de RPM del motor no se mantiene estable al ralentí, sino que oscila entre dos valores.

Answer (score 4):

I would say something like:

"El coche vibra cuando está parado."

Answer (score 3):

"Ralenti" is French, so no wonder the term is used in Spain where there is strong neighborly influence (even though Spaniards will deny it).

In Mexico I would use "neutral", and my guess is that this is quite generic. Automatic transmissions have "Neutral", but it is used also for stick-shift: when the engine is not engaged, you say "está en neutral".

I would suggest a descriptive approach when talking to your mechanic: "el coche hace ruido cuando está en neutral". This sound better than a word-by-word translation like "tiene una neutral ruidosa".

One last point. In Spanish the stress in "neutral" is in the last syllable: "neuTRAL" as opposed to English "NEUtral".